# Elasticsearch: add new fields to an existing documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to add to an existing document matched by a query a new object with new fields.

```
PUT test/_doc/1
{ 
 "id" : 1,
 "text": "My life is beautiful"
 "category": "optimistic"
}
```

I would like to add to all the "category":"optimistic" documents, a new object, something like

```
{"references": {
   "group": "Pro-life",
   "responsable": "Mr. Happy Guy"
   "job": "Happiness bringer"
}
```

I would like to try with `update_by_query` but I cannot make it work with object like this. Any ideas?

I did try with this:

```
{
     "script": "ctx._source.references='{\"hello\":\"world\"}'",
     "query": {
        "match": {
            "category": "optimistic"
        }
     }
}
```

But it doesn't give me the expected results. It just saved it as a string `"""{"hello":"world"}"""`
whilst I wanted it as JSON object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested but you could try with `params` along with `update_by_query`,

```
{
     "query": {
        "match": {
            "category": "optimistic"
        }
     },
     "script": {
       "inline": "ctx._source.references = params.new_fields",
       "params": {
       "new_fields": {
           "group": "Pro-life",
           "responsable": "Mr. Happy Guy"
           "job": "Happyness bringer"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. It works, `inline` (in es > v7.x) is deprecated though: `#! Deprecation: Deprecated field [inline] used, expected [source] instead`

Comment: @salvob glad it helps you somehow. Thnx for the deprecation info :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `painless` syntax to do that, try it like that:

```
"script": "ctx._source.references=[ \"hello\":\"world\" ]"
```

More info: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-operators-reference.html#map-initialization-operator

Comment: thank you, but this adds just one field, and I need a JSON object in the update